# How to block the MAC Address in Huawei HG532e wireless router?

Tags: wireless-router, blocking, mac-address, blacklist

I am using a Huawei HG532e wireless router and I would like to block some of the smart phones of some of the workers who are no more working with us. Please help me to do this work as early as possible they just come around to use the network and download whatever they want though they are no longer with us.

Comment: Blocking a device by its MAC Address is not effective.  Why don't you just change the password to the network?  **You can always just ask them to leave.**

Comment: I highly recomend you to change password rather that blacklisting MAC as it's very easy to bypass MAC blacklist/whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by signing into your router admin page, going to advanced > Filter and drop in the MAC address as well as the start and end times/days for the filter. If you block the MAC 7 days a week from 00:01 to 23:59 ,it should accomplish what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You first need to access the router settings by going to:

```
http://192.168.1.1/
```

If you can't access, you need to change your network settings.

Huawei's default username is **user** and default password is also **user**.

Then, in the settings, you need to go to:

```
Basic (in the sidebar)
  WLAN (below)
    WLAN Filtering (this is a tab)
```

Click in *enable* and wait a little.

Then select **blacklist**, pick the SSID of the network you need to work on and type the MAC address you need to ban. Now you just need to save that.

Hope that helps.